# Specman reflection: How to use get_method()?

Tags: reflection, specman

Hi I would like to write a general method `check_range()` that gets as parameter `raw_type` (`vin` or `vout` or `il` etc.) and according to the `raw_type` calls relevant method `calc_vin()` or `calc_vout()` etc. I try to use reflection `get_method()` for it:

```
type raw_t : [vin, vout, il, iin];
...
extend my_unit {

    check_range(raw_type : raw_t) : uint {
        var meth_name : string = appendf("calc_%s", raw_type);
        var meth : rf_method = me.get_method(meth_name); //This line causes an error
        // ....
    };

    calc_vout() is {
        // Calculates Vout
    };

};
```

When I invoke the `check_range()` method I get the **error**:

```
Error: 'me' (of type my_unit_u) does not have 'get_method()' method.
```

How can I approach the `calc_vout()` method using reflection `get_method()`? Really appreciate your help

Comment: This seems like misusing reflection. You should use a `case` statement to call the appropriate method based on the input argument.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to work with the reflection facility, you need to use the "rf_struct" of my_unit_u.

Specifically, try the following:

```
type raw_t : [vin, vout, il, iin];
...
extend my_unit {

check_range(raw_type : raw_t) : uint {
    var meth_name : string = appendf("calc_%s", raw_type);
    var my_unit_rf := rf_manager.get_struct_of_instance(me);
    var meth : rf_method = my_unit_rf.get_method(meth_name); 
    // ....
};

calc_vout() is {
    // Calculates Vout
};
```

};

Comment: In addition, to actually call the method, you can use `rf_method.invoke()`. I've edited Ynon's example to show this, too.